# Retrieving HTML code used in google docs using google app scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to use Google app scripts to get the html code in Google docs i.e if text in the document was say bold,i could get the html code for that.
What i have so far :

```
function getHtml(id) {

var doc1=DocsListExtended.getFileById("1ta7zJ6SDFgzgp-UprjehxR8Tx3-4-wtJwTYqWbol1SU").getAsHTML();
var body=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(doc1);
var cont=body.getContent();
return cont;
  Logger.log(cont);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a simple way for that.  You can navigate the elements of the document using DocumentApp API, and converting it block by block to HTML.

I already tried

```
DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getAs(MimeType.HTML).getDataAsString()
```

but the error says doc can't be converted to html mimetype.

Comment: I was able to get the code to work but now the issue is when i send the html as an email the css gets lost.The code as per now:

Comment: function myFunction()                                                                                              {
                                                                                                                        var doc1=DocsListExtended.getFileById("1WxPG2nlsxYfgxX56XkYkHVJADwPsWE9pFABaPpQgc7w").getAs.HTML();
  var body=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(doc1);
  Logger.log(doc1);
  MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: "wambui.njage@gmail.com",
     subject: "CodeBlocks",
     htmlBody: (body.getContent())
              
        });
}